# Reference problem (I guess) when using boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, httpclient, boost-asio

I am building an HTTP client based on the example on HTTP server given at [boost website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/). Now, the difference between that code and mine is that the example uses the server constructor to start the asynchronous operations. This makes sense since a server is supposed to listen all the time. In my client, on the other hand, I want to first construct the object and then have a `send()` function that starts off by connecting to the endpoint and later on sends a request and finally listens for the reply. This makes sense too, doesn't it?

When I create my object (client) I do it in the same manner as in the server example (winmain.cpp). It looks like this:

```
client c("www.boost.org);
c.start(); // starts the io_service in a thread
c.send(msg_);
```

The relevant parts of the code are these:

```
void enabler::send(common::geomessage& msg_)
{
    new_connection_.reset(new connection(io_service_,
        connection_manager_,
        message_manager_, msg_
    ));

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(host_address, "http");

    resolver.async_resolve(query, boost::bind(
        &enabler::handle_resolve,
        boost::ref(*this),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::iterator
    ));
}

void enabler::run()
{
    io_service_.run();
}
```

The problem with this is that the program gets stuck somewhere here. The last thing that prints is the "Resolving host", after that the program ends. I don't know why because the `io_service` should block until all async operations have returned to their callbacks. If, however, I change the order of how I call the functions, it works. If I call `run()` just after the call to `async_resolve()` and also omit calling `start()` in my main program, it works!

In this scenario, `io_service` blocks as it should and I can see that I get a response from the server.

It has something to do from the fact that I call `run()` from inside the same class as where I call `async_resolve()`. Could this be true? The I suppose I need to give a reference from the main program when I call `run()`, is it like that?

I have struggled with getting `io_service::work` to work but the program just gets stuck and yeah, similar problems as the one above occur. So it does not really help.

So, what can I do to get this right? As I said earlier, what I want is to be able to create the client object and have the `io_service` running all the time in a separate thread inside the client class. Secondly to have a function, `send()`, that sends requests to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't expect to have some work at all times, to keep the io_service busy, you should construct an `io_service::work` object in some scope which can be exited without `io_service::run()` having to return first. If you're running the `io_service` in a separate thread, I would imagine you wouldn't have a problem with that.

It's sort of hard to know what you're trying to do with those snippets of code. I imagine that you'd want to do something along these lines:

```
struct client
{
   io_service io_service_;
   io_service::work* w_;
   pthread_t main_thread_;
   client(): w_(new io_service::work(io_service)) { ... }
   void start() { pthread_create(&main_thread_, 0, main_thread, this); }
   static long main_thread(void* arg) { ((client*)arg)->io_service_.run(); }
   // release the io_service and allow run() to return
   void stop() { delete w_; w_ = 0; pthread_join(main_thread_); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to start at least some work before calling `run()`, as it returns when there is no more work to do.

If you call it before you start the async resolve, it won't have any work so it returns.

Comment: Thanks, that explains some at least. I could call run() in the function send() just after async_resolve(). But the problem is that if run() has already been called, it would be wrong to call it again. You see I want to use send() so that one could send requests before the current run() has finished. Is there a way to determine if the io_service has finished, and thereby determine if it is safe to call run again? If that would work, it would be good because then I could just have an if-statement checking this.

Comment: It sounds like what you could really use is to let run() go indefinitely, so you never have to worry about it?  The asio docs have a [section just for that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.stopping_the_io_service_from_running_out_of_work).

Comment: Yes! Thats exactly what I want! But I have already read the page you referred to and I can't get this thing with ioservice::work to work... I have an io_service defined as a private variable of client class. In my run() function I have tried this:

boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service_);
io_service_.run();

Then to stop the entire thing I am supposed to call io_service_.stop(); Is that correct? Because I just can' get it to work

Comment: That sounds right.  Maybe edit your question with some code showing it, so I can see what's wrong?

Comment: Sure, I will do that. But it says I have to wait 8 hours before I can post answers to my own questions because I am a new user. Will post it tomorrow when I'm back. Thanks!